# Arguments to update_attribute change in SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, carrierwave

## The gist of it all

**This method call:**

```
user.update_attribute('image_url', 'arch.png')
```

**Generates this SQL statement:**

```
UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, [["image_url", "rock.jpg"]]
```

**That SQL statement is not what the desired outcome is.**

The desired outcome is this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, [["image_url", "arch.png"]]
```

Notice that the SQL statement generated has the wrong argument for `image_url`.

- How is that possible though?
- How can I fix it?

---

### Background

I use the `form_for` tag to generate a form where users can change their profile picture. The form sends a post request to the controller which calls another method, passing along the parameters. The final method calls `update_attribute` on the record, saving the changes.

I'm using the gem "carrierwave" for the images.

---

## Debugging

I've done some debugging and it looks like everything goes well, until the last method calls `update_attribute`. That call generates a SQL statement which is incorrect.

For reference purposes, the old picture's file name is "rock.jpg", and the new one is "arch.png".

The gist of it is that these two lines are executed:

```
puts "\n\nSending #{attribute} and #{value} to update_attribute\n\n" 
if user.update_attribute(attribute, value)
```

Which result in:

```
Sending image_url and arch.png to update_attribute

UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["image_url", "rock.jpg"], [...]]
```

I took out the updated_at part of the generated SQL statement, since it isn't important. The full SQL statement as well as more output from the helper can be seen just below.

- **How is the `image_url` in the SQL statement different from the value passed to it?**

### Detailed output from log

```
Received update request!!!!!
---------------------------
Attribute - image_url
Value - arch.png
--------------------------

Sending image_url and arch.png to update_attribute

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 186]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["image_url", "rock.jpg"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-27 01:25:49.476024"], ["id", 186]]
   (90.4ms)  commit transaction
```

---

### Code

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@current_member, html: {id: 'image_form'}) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :image_url, 
    type: 'file', html: {id: 'file_field'} %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'updateParam', 'image_url' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def update
  update_account(@current_member, params[:updateParam], params)
end
```

**Helper:**

```
def update_account(user, attribute, parameters)

  puts "\n\n\n\n\n"
  puts "Received update request!!!!!\n
  puts "---------------------------\n"
  puts "Attribute - #{attribute}\n"
  puts "Value - #{parameters[attribute]}\n"
  puts "--------------------------\n\n\n"

  if editable attribute
    if valid(attribute, parameters)
      value = parameters[attribute]

      puts "\n\nSending #{attribute} and #{value} to update_attribute\n\n"
    
      if user.update_attribute(attribute, value)

      # ...
      # ...
```

---

## The gist of it all

**This method call:**

```
user.update_attribute('image_url', 'arch.png')
```

**Generates this SQL statement:**

```
UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, [["image_url", "rock.jpg"]]
```

**That SQL statement is not what the desired outcome is.**

The desired outcome is this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE "users" SET "image_url" = ?, [["image_url", "arch.png"]]
```

Notice that the SQL statement generated has the wrong argument for `image_url`.

- How is that possible?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear now. The question is, "how do I get the SQL statement generated that I expect to get?"

Comment: That is funny.  I'm sure it is a typo.  I'd check and make sure you don't have a typo in a variable name or array index.

Comment: What is the return value of update_attribute, false?

Comment: @Hogan It can't be false, as it isn't hard-coded. I just added in the detailed output from the log. There you can see that the method passes in those two arguments, then the SQL statement has something different.

Comment: @GustavoRubio It returns true, actually.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Can you use `update_column` in place of `update_attribute` and see what does it return?http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Comment: @dkp It changed the SQL statement to what I wanted! But why didn't the first method work? What's the difference?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt I think there might be some callback in your model, which is changing the things. Whereas `update_column` does not execute either `validations` or `callbacks`.

Comment: @dkp Thanks, do you know how I can find the callback in question?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt `callbacks` are hard to tackle. please check your `User` model if it has something like `before_save` or `before_update` or `around_save` ?

Comment: @dkp I've figured out the problem, but only thanks to your help. If you'd like to make an answer, I'll gladly accept it and comment the debugging steps I took after following your advice.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt glad you nailed it! I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending comments to answer:

It looks, there is some callback in your model which is changing the `value` before save/update.

To skip callbacks, you can use [`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) instead of `update_attribute`.

*Note: `update_column` also skips validations and does not update the `updated_at` attribute.*

---

#### Edit from author

This answer was right, a callback changed the result to something that could be saved in the database.

Using `update_column` I was able to see that my parameters were passed in correctly, but were not correct. The `carrierwave` gem uses a callback which checks to see if the parameter is valid, if not, it reverts the value to what it was previous to the call. If the value is valid (an UploadedFile), then it saves the file in the save_dir and changes the value to be a url to point to the file.

I used this to debug further and find that the value I passed to `update_attribute` wasn't valid because the `form_for` didn't include `multipart: true`, which is necessary for forms using carrierwave to upload images. Adding this solved the problem.

I had to go back to using `update_attribute` instead of `update_column` so that `carrierwave`'s callback would still be executed and the uploaded file would be saved in the database.

Comment: I've added an edit for the debugging I needed to do. If you'd rather, I can shorten and just write about it in the comments though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of clutter in your question, this makes it hard to read and help. 
The goal of such a bug hunt is to reduce the elements involved to have as few things to worry about as possible.

#### Bypass Rails

Run the statement in a SQL console. Just to be sure that you don't have any fancy triggers and functions in place. From the output you showed, this should not be the case. But... It costs you 1min. and gives you some security.

#### Bypass View/Controller

Run the code on the Rails console. I tend to write everything on one line, with a `reload!` statement in front. So changes in the code can be checked fast:

```
reload!; user = User.find(12345); user.update_attribute('image_url', 'arch.png'); User.find(12345).image_url
```

What does it print?
I assume that your problem stems from callbacks. So it should print the wrong value for image_url already. So you can be sure that the problem is not caused by View/Controller layer.

#### Bypass View

If everything is fine, then you can be sure that the problem is somewhere in View/Controller. In this case i'd not use `params` to build the update statement but use hardcoded values. Like this you bypass the View layer.

#### Bypass callbacks

Use `update_column` instead of `update_attribute`

### Callbacks

First: don't use callbacks. Second: don't use them. And if you use them be damn sure you know what you do:-)

If `update_column` solves the problem, then it probably is because of a callback.
Search your code for the attribute name and callback names to see if there are any.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the advice! You were completely correct, only a minute too late.